# Populate DropDownList Using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I trying to populate dropdownlist using EF, with 
`DataValueField= Terr_TerritoryID`
and `DataTextField=Terr_Caption`

In sql this is the command:

```
select Terr_Caption,Terr_TerritoryID 
from Territories 
where Terr_TerritoryID in (-1342177274,-1073741819,-805306364,-536870909,-268435454,268435456,1)
```

when I tried to write this sql using EF, like this:

```
var tc = (from t in db.Territories
          where t.Terr_TerritoryID == -1342177274 && 
                t.Terr_TerritoryID == -1073741819 && 
                t.Terr_TerritoryID == -805306364 && 
                t.Terr_TerritoryID == -805306364
           select new
           {
               terCapt = t.Terr_Caption,
               terID = t.Terr_TerritoryID    
           });

ddlTer.DataSource = tc.ToList();
ddlTer.DataValueField = "terID";
ddlTer.DataTextField = "terCapt";
ddlTer.DataBind();
```

when I execute nothing appeared in dropDownlist.

what is happening, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator in the where should be `OR` and not `AND`. The same id can be both the first and the second and the third etc. values - but it can be x ory or z.

```
from t in db.Territories
where t.Terr_TerritoryID == -1342177274 || 
      t.Terr_TerritoryID == -1073741819 || 
      t.Terr_TerritoryID == -805306364 || 
      t.Terr_TerritoryID == -805306364
select new
{
    terCapt = t.Terr_Caption,
    terID = t.Terr_TerritoryID
};
```

Even better is create a list of the values and use `.Contains`:

```
var ids = new List<int> { -1342177274, -1073741819, -805306364, -805306364 };

from t in db.Territories
where ids.Contains(t.Terr_TerritoryID)
select new
{
    terCapt = t.Terr_Caption,
    terID = t.Terr_TerritoryID
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my problem

Comment: but why the second sol is better ?

Comment: @FaresAyyad - you are welcome :) Glad it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

**With Lambda**

```
var ids = new List<int> { -1342177274, -1073741819, -805306364, -805306364 };
    var tc= db.Territories.where(x=>ids.Contains(x.Terr_TerritoryID))
            .select new
            {
            terCapt = t.Terr_Caption,
            terID = t.Terr_TerritoryID
            };
            .ToList();
```